# Condensing multiple addClass

Tags: jquery

Silly question, but I couldn't find an answer online.
Is there a way to add a class or remove a class to multiple items at one time? I'm trying to clean up code, and there are many instances where I would like to condense this.

```
$('#div1').addClass('active');
$('#div2').addClass('active');
$('#div3').addClass('active');
$('#div4').addClass('active');
```

Comment: how about `$('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4').addClass('active');` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing to do with `addClass`, just with your jQuery selector.  You can separate multiple selectors with commas.  For example:

```
$('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you can modify your selector to tackle multiple items at the same time.

However, if you are able to, I would recommend adding your own class to the related HTML elements you want to act upon.

I.e. if you are able add a class to your `div` elements, like

`<div id="div1" class="group1">Div 1</div>`

then you can use those for selection of any number of elements at the same time.  See sample code below.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#toggleGroup1").on('click', function() {
    $(".group1").each(function(idx, element) {
      $(element).toggleClass('active');
    });
  });

  $("#toggleGroup2").on('click', function() {
    $(".group2").each(function(idx, element) {
      $(element).toggleClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.group1.active {
  background-color: green;
}

.group2.active {
  background-color: orange;
}

div {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="group1">Div one</div>
<div id="div2" class="group1">Div two</div>
<div id="div3" class="group1">Div three</div>
<div id="div4" class="group1">Div four</div>
<div id="div5" class="group2">Div five</div>
<div id="div6" class="group2">Div six</div>
<div id="div7" class="group2">Div seven</div>

<br/><br/>
<button id="toggleGroup1">Toggle Class Group1</button>
<button id="toggleGroup2">Toggle Class Group2</button>
```

Comment: This is for temporary classes to show, hide, highlight items. They can't be added directly into the html because that would impede the functionality. :)

Comment: @zazvorniki hmmm, I understand if you cannot do it for other reasons but adding your own 'grouping' classes won't impede any functionality (it'll just give you the ability to group related items for manipulation purposes) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯